# Does declaring a variable as optional incurs any additional cost in swift?

Tags: swift2

As per my boss, if I am initialising a variable in init, I should not declare it as optional and he thinks book on swift says that.

Now I haven't came across the same statement anywhere hence wondering is he correct or not.

**OverView:**

As I come from an Object oriented Objective C programming background, it is my hobby to declare the variables to their initial values as soon as I declare it (most of the Stanford university videos on Objective C said the same thing) Now objective C used to allow a nil value to the variables and if I want to assign the same nil value as initial value to some variable in swift I need to declare it as optional, I know that if I declare a variable and won't initialise it in init I'll get error from compiler,

```
struct TestStruct {
    var name : String? = nil
    var age : Int

    init(){
        name = "Sandeep"
        age = 26
    }

    func printInfo(){
        print(self.name! + "\(self.age)")
    }
}
```

In the above code I have name declared as optional and set nil as default value where as age is defined as Int and initialised to proper value in init.

**Question**

Knowing that both work,

1.Is it wrong if I declare a variable as optional and then use ! or ? to access it even though I initialise it in init??

2.Is it true that swift specifies that I should not use ? or ! for the variables ? If yes is there any added computational cost to it ?

I know it is not a complicated question, I just wanna know what I am doing is anyway wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make a variable optional if `nil` is a valid value for it to have.

Comment: I don't use swift, but I do use similar languages and my vote is that you default to non-nil but if it makes sense for the value to be optional then it should be nullable. As the value is set in the initialiser for this struct though `name` will never be nil, so it should not be optional

Comment: @dan-pantry : I agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to reset your struct's name to nil ever, initialize the variables with the values you want them to have.  It simplifies the code and expresses the idea of default values.

```
struct TestStruct {
    var name = "Sandeep"
    var age = 26

    func printInfo(){
        print(self.name + "\(self.age)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely agree with you :) Hence I have up voted your answer, but if I do declare a variable as optional is that wrong ??? Or is it a bad coding practice ?? Is there any additional cost which I am ignoring. Though the question I posted has simple fields like name age I use similar approach in my network layer design, like my web service manager holds the alamofireManager object as optional and I initialise it in init. Now alamofireManager instance might get nil at some point  in execution and I don't want it to crash when that happens hence I declare it as optional

Comment: but the code reviewer thinks that anyway am initialising alamofireManager in init so there is no need to declare it as optional, As per him if the alamofireManager instance is nil there is no use of web service manager so he is ok if alamofireManager instance gets nil at some point application should crash (though I find it really strange to accept it but thats what am dealing with) As per him swift book specifies that I should not use optional if am initialising it in init. Hence am wondering is swift anyway says that ?? Or If I do what I do is that a bug ???

Comment: To be clear, if it's not an optional, you can't make it be nil.  (Implicitly unwrapped optionals are still optionals.)  In my opinion, declaring something optional that can never have a nil value is bad practice because it gives the person reading it incorrect expectations and because it requires extra code (`!` or `if let`) to check for a condition that will never happen.

Comment: So, if the variable can become nil, using an optional isn't a decision any more, it's a requirement.  (How to initialize them is then a matter of style and convenience.)  If there's no chance of them becoming nil, then you might still decide to make them optional...but I'm not coming up with any good reasons to support that.

Comment: I completely agree with you :) Its just the fact that swift says I should not declare a variable as optional if I initialise it in init was little disturbing as I have not read such thing in any of the official book. Now though I agree declaring a variable as optional will add a additional code like ? or ! or if let I believe we can handle nil conditions gracefully if at any point variable turns to nil with optional variable as normal variable will result in crash. alamofireManager?.response makes more stable code I believe than alamofireManager.response :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your boss is correct but it depends on the requirements. If you are for sure that you would be having a `name` and `age` then you can avoid `optionals` for these two. If you are not sure about the values then you should use the `optionals` like for address or phone number etc. And also it is best practice to initialize with the parameters in the `struct` like below:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var name : String?
    var age : Int

    init(name: String?, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    func printInfo(){
        //Since your name property is an optional, you should check for a nil before using it.
        print("Name:", (self.name ?? "") + "\nAge: \(self.age)")
    }
}

let myStruct = TestStruct(name: "Sandeep", age: 26)
myStruct.printInfo()

//output
Name: Sandeep
Age: 26

let myStruct2 = TestStruct(name: nil, age: 18)
myStruct2.printInfo()

//output 
Name: No Name provided
Age: 18
```

Comment: I agree with you buddy, hence the up vote. But all am asking is, is optional variables costs something ?? Why should I try avoid them when having them can be used for advantage like handling nil cases gracefully. Please see my comments on phillip's answer to understand my scenario clearly.

Comment: Not at all wrong using optionals and it doesn't cost anything. Optionals in Swift allows us to discover potential issues at compile-time, thus prevent unexpected errors at runtime. Non-optional vars should be avoided at most time because you never know when the values becomes nil and program crashes. Only you know at the time of development that there is 100% value, what if the service changes in future? what if someone is not providing values to your class/struct? In such cases there is a requirement for recoding/modifying etc. There would be so many such cases would come.